# How to find an element in PageLoad callback with Jquery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, pageload

I met a strange problem today. In my jquery mobile project, i load a page from index.html. I hooked the pageload event to update the default value of input in the external page. With Jquery mobile 1.3.2, my program works fine. But after i moved to Jquery 1.4.5, i could catch the event, but i could not find the specified input element in the callback. I searched the API document, it seems the pageload event is deprecate in 1.4.0, and it is suggested to use pagecontainerload. But the result is the same. I still could not find the element. It is so weird. Can someone take a look at my code and give me any tips? The following is my code:
bonon.js:

```
  $(document).bind("pageload",function(event,data1){
        var url=data1.url;
        var uri=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"),url.lastIndexOf("."));

        if(uri=="/page2"||uri=="/zhgl"||uri=="/jymxcx"||uri=="/zzmxcx")
        {
            $("#inputtest").val("haha");
            alert($("#inputtest").val());
        }

    });
```

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Icons - jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
            <!--
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
            <script src='js/bonbon.js'></script>
            <style id="custom-icon">
                .ui-icon-myicon:after {
                    background-image: url("_assets/img/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png");
                    /* Make your icon fit */
                    background-size: 18px 18px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" data-quicklinks="true">
            <div data-demo-html="true" data-demo-css="#custom-icon">
                <button id="mybutton" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-myicon">myicon</button>
                </div>
                <a href="page2.html"> click me </a>
                <a href="#" onclick="window.location='hbuilderindex.html'"> hbuilder me </a>
        </div><!-- /page -->

        </body>
        </html>
```

This is page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='page2' data-role="page" class="jqm-demos">
            <div data-role='content'>
            <input id="inputtest" value="123" />    
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for the element in the fetched page, instead, you are referring to first `input` in DOM with id `inputtest`.

`pagecontainerload`'s data returns many objects. Two them contain fetched HTML, `data.toPage` and `data.page`. Use any of them to find elements of that page.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerload", function (event, data1) {
    var url = data1.url;
    var uri = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.lastIndexOf("."));

    if (uri == "/page2" || uri == "/zhgl" || uri == "/jymxcx" || uri == "/zzmxcx") {
        $("#inputtest", data1.toPage).val("haha");
        /* or data1.toPage.find("#inputtest").val("haha"); */
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DavQQjvg3Rr4d7bpTbmR?p=preview)**

Comment: Ah, I got it. Very appreciate your help Omar. Yes. I can see the toPage includes all elements of the fetched HTML.

Comment: @ping you're welcome :) use `.page` when you _load_ page `.pagecontainer("load", "page.html")`. Use `.toPage` when you navigate to a page.